# How do I integrate iconic.js with a Meteor app?

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to use the iconic.js package with meteor but I have no idea how to get it to work. I tried adding a local package that includes iconic.min.js and then did the following:

```
    <img class="iconic" data-src="/iconic/smart/envelope.svg">
```

But no luck on loading anything. Any tips?

https://useiconic.com/tools/iconic-js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic Docs

> After your page loads you might also want to inject some SVGs. This is a common case when building single-page applications and using front-end libraries and frameworks like Angular, Backbone and Ember, or when making calls like jQuery.load(), that make DOM changes and add icons after the initial automatic injection occurs.

I guess that includes Meteor too, since the DOM isn't always ready when the page loads.

So its just running this in your `Template.hello.rendered = function() {...}` callback, for the template containing these icons:

```
var iconic = IconicJS();
iconic.inject('img.iconic');
```